# ValueError: I/O operation on closed (csv) file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 7, in <module>
    for review in x:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Code:

```
def get_reviews(path):
    with open(path, 'r', encoding = "utf-8") as file1:
        reviews = map(lambda x: x.strip().split(','), file1)
        return reviews

x = get_reviews("reviews.csv")
for review in x:
    print(review)
```

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: BTW, you should use `csv.reader` to read CSV files, your code doesn't handle quoting and escaping properly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: `get_reviews()` returns is a generator, which doesn't execute until the `for review in x:` statement, but the file has been closed by then because the `with` has closed `file1`.

Comment: the error happen on line 7

Comment: @Prune I pasted his code into a text file and reproduced it. What's missing?

Comment: you can cast the map object into a list to make it work outside the `open` context

Comment: The `for review in x:` statement is the what I said.

Comment: @Barmar: the post is missing the full error message (which I've since supplied) and the data file to validate a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, the `map()` function does not process the input object entirely, but merely returns an iterator over it. So the file doesn't actually get processed until your `for` loop calls for each line. But by that time, the file has been closed, since your code left the `with` block.

You have two choices here. First, you can have the caller pass in an open file, and make them handle opening and closing the file:

```
def get_reviews(rev_file):
    return map(lambda x: x.strip().split(','), rev_file)

with open(path) as file1:
    for review in get_reviews(file1):
        print(review)
```

Or else have `get_reviews()` fully process the file, say by returning a list.

```
def get_reviews(path):
    with open(path, 'r', encoding = "utf-8") as file1:
        return list(map(lambda x: x.strip().split(','), file1))

# alternate version using a list comprehension instead of map()
def get_reviews(path):
    with open(path, 'r', encoding = "utf-8") as file1:
       return [x.strip().split(',') for x in file1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reviews = map(lambda x: x.strip().split(','), 
             [_ for _ in file1] )
```

you returned a generator on the file object.  That file was closed when you left the `with` block in the function.